# JUnit switch from Suite to AllTests causes annotations to not be run

Tags: java, junit4

Previously I used Suite.class to specify tests to run for certain suite with following scheme of structure:
**Suite**

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({TC0.class, TC1.class...})
public class mainTester {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {//create xml report - create file, start xml structure}
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown(){//close xml report - close xml structure, close writer
}
```

**Tests**

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TC0 extends testXMLReporter{
    //Tests with params
}
```

and lastly **testXMLReporter** holding rule

```
@Rule
public TestRule watchman = new TestWatcher(){
    //@Override apply, succeeded, failed to write custom xml structure for xml report
}
```

But since now I need to create suites dynamically reading data from file I switched from Suite.class to `AllTests.class`. The only thing to make it work was to change my **Suite**
- removing `@SuiteClasses`
- changing `@RunWith` value to `AllTests.class`
- and adding `suite()` method

```
public static TestSuite suite() {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
    for(Class<?> klass : CsvParser.readCSV()) {
        suite.addTest(new junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter(klass));
    }
    return suite;
}
```

Runs like charm in terms of reading file and running tests but now all of the sudden my `@Before`/AfterClass annotations as well as `@Rule` is not running (my report is no longer created). What is the reason for that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I gave up using exclusively `AllTests.class` and now use `Suite.class` to call `AllTests.class`. Example:

**main**

```
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(intercessor.class);
```

**intercessor**

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({mainTester.class})
public class intercessor {
    //do Before & After
}
```

**mainTester**

```
@RunWith(AllTests.class)
public class mainTester {

    public static TestSuite suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();

        for(Class<?> klass : CsvParser.readCSV()) {
            suite.addTest(new junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter(klass));
        }

        return suite;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps somebody in the future